# R: Residuals from Linear Models in List

Tags: r, lm

I have a series of linear models that I've run and I want to be able to output the residuals from specific years and match those residuals to the companies.

The data looks similar to that shown below

```
Year    Company         pctEarn
1990    3M Company      0.295918367
1991    AT&T            0.251497006
1992    Ford            0.293233083
1993    Microsoft       0.264705882
```

The loop to run through the LMs looks like below

```
fits <- list()

for(i in 2000:2012){
  dtSub <- subset(dt, Year <= i)
  fit <- lm(pctEarn ~ Year + Company, data = dtSub)
  fits[[i - 1999]] <- fit
}
```

What I'm having issues with is retrieving the residuals for specific companies from the output.

Ideally I'd be able to create an output for each regression that looks like below

```
Year Company    pctEarn    Predicted  Residual
1990 3M Company 0.2959     0.4523     0.16000
Etc......
```

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: There is an extraction function `resid`.

Comment: Also for `predict`. So perhaps not essential to store all the info. returned by each fit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I figured out which isn't ideal for large regressions is to simply build up a data frame that accumulates regression results and I can cut it up later.

```
out <- data.frame()
for(i in 2000:2012){
  dtSub <- subset(dt, Year <= i)
  fit <- lm(pctEarn ~ y2 + Company, data = dtSub)
  fits[[i - 1999]] <- fit
  dtSub$fitted <- fitted(fit)
  dtSub$resid <- residuals(fit)
  dtSub$reg <- i
  out <- rbind(out, dtSub)
}
```